# Undefined parameters passed into onMove method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-absolute-grid (https://github.com/jrowny/react-absolute-grid) to display a set of images.

I have the following `onMove` method:

```
  onMove: function(source, target) {
    var sampleItems = this.state.items
    source = _.find(sampleItems, {key: parseInt(source, 10)});
    target = _.find(sampleItems, {key: parseInt(target, 10)});

    var targetSort = target.sort;

    //CAREFUL, For maximum performance we must maintain the array's order, but change sort
    sampleItems.forEach(function(item){
      //Decrement sorts between positions when target is greater
      if(target.sort > source.sort && (item.sort <= target.sort && item.sort > source.sort)){
        item.sort --;
      //Incremenet sorts between positions when source is greator
      }else if(item.sort >= target.sort && item.sort < source.sort){
        item.sort ++;
      }
    });

    source.sort = targetSort;

    this.setState({items: sampleItems})
  },
```

Which I copy pasted from the demo here: https://github.com/jrowny/react-absolute-grid/blob/733b3f752e2b9af7314029bb64fb883f2a28a6a8/demo.js

Also, I am displaying the grid like this:

```
<AbsoluteGrid
  items={this.state.countries}
  displayObject={<DisplayObject/>}
  onMove={onMoveDebounced}
  dragEnabled={true}
  responsive={true}
  verticalMargin={42}
  itemWidth={250}
  itemHeight={250}
  filteredProp={'name'}
/>
```

The issues is that whenever I try to move a picture I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
```

That is because both of the parameters passed here `onMove: function(source, target) {`  are `undefined`.

Why is that the case?
How can I make sure that parameters are passed properly?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing items, probably some HTML template. Sure you copied the whole code from the demo?

Comment: The object that I am displaying in the grid `displayObject={<DisplayObject/>}` is completely different. Could that be the issue? Why would the HTML template affect the JavaScript code?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with React, just using my general JS knowledge and common sense. The code is looking for "items" in the state, and can't find those items (meaning can't find the desired items). So I assume the items are defined as some sort of template, or repeater, in the HTML. Check the HTML part of the demo, or the part where they define the items.